# Build Docker in VM

Tags: build, docker, virtual-machine

I want to implement a Docker Storage Driver that uses a custom storage system.

However, from what I have seen so far Docker can only be built inside a container. Is it possible to build it natively in my host system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building outside the canonical build-container is definitely supported (although not recommended); I usually use a one-liner like `AUTO_GOPATH=1 ./hack/make.sh dynbinary` to accomplish this (especially useful for bootstrapping a machine that doesn't have Docker yet).

This is also how distribution packages compile Docker, so it's worth checking out the dedicated packager documentation for details about how to use `make.sh` directly:
https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/v1.9.1/project/PACKAGERS.md
(including an explanation of what `AUTO_GOPATH` above does among other useful environment variables)

Answer (score 0):

Docker runs on Linux. If you're not, then install Linux on your host.